# Android music player source code

Tags: java, android-source, android-music-player

I need native (default) android music player source code. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 20):

It’s all on [source.android.com](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html); you can browse the [list of packages](https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML), and the Music app is located at [platform/packages/apps/Music.git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music).

There’s a mirror on [github.com/android](https://github.com/android). You can browse the source code of the Music app online at [platform_packages_apps_music](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music), with GitHub’s fancier interface.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look, here is the link for `platform/frameworks/base`:
 https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base